# error saying it cant convert string to bool

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am trying to write a function that echo's the input if my script is running in debug mode.

```
[bool]$debugmode = $true
#one liner version for manually pasting into the powershell console
#Function DebugWrite-Output([bool]$isDebug,$inputObject){if ($isDebug -eq $true){Write-Output $inputObject}}
Function DebugWrite-Output([bool]$isDebug,$inputObject)
    {if ($isDebug -eq $true){
        Write-Output $inputObject
    }
}
DebugWrite-Output -isDebug = $debugmode -inputObject "Loading create access file function"
```

the error i get is

```
DebugWrite-Output : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'isDebug'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as 
$True, $False, 1 or 0.
At C:\Users\*****\source\repos\Powershell Scripts\Modular-Export.ps1:9 char:28
+ DebugWrite-Output -isDebug = $debugmode -inputObject "Loading create  ...
+                            ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [DebugWrite-Output], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,DebugWrite-Output
```

This error doesnt make sense to me since i am passing a boolean into the boolean and a string into the psobject.

Comment: You want `[switch]`, not a boolean flag.

Comment: son of a... well post as answer so i can accept it @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: this >>> `-isDebug = $debugmode` <<< is NOT valid code. [*grin*] the parameter `-isDebug` is expecting a [bool] and you gave it a string that starts with an '='.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1. Correct your syntax error:  You must pass parameters in the form of `-param [value]`:

   ```
   -isDebug $debugmode
   ```
2. Use the right tool for the job, a `[switch]` parameter:

   ```
   function DebugWrite-Output([switch] $isDebug, $inputObject) {
       if ($isDebug.IsPresent) { ...
   ```

   Then you call it by just including the switch:

   ```
   -isDebug
   ```